# Background process to alert the user in iphone?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am developing a iphone uiwebview based application to load an web application url by getting the user credential from a login screen,as i have username and password which are required to communicate with the server on the other end with web services,i want to make an 
alert with some data to the user once after he logged into application.

But can i able to give that alert even he closes my application if then please suggest me how to do so?

I mean can i run any background service that can allow me to communicate some server with webservice calls and alert the user?

Thanks in advance......

Comment: iPhone OS 3 or 4? Do you mean Push Notification or Offline Notifications?

For web services, use Push. You must be able to modify the web service.

Comment: I am using os 4 ,but i dont want to change anything in my server end,but want to give an alert to the user after he logged in and also even he closes the application

Comment: Can u please tell me  what you mean by offline notifications

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you need to implement a push notification service for your app. Did you have a look at Apples documentation on local and push notifications? http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Or have a look at thee WWDC Video about it on iTunes.